# Autodiscover for IMAP over SSL

Tags: imap, email-server, autodiscovery

Is it possible to setup Autodiscover for your domain.com without the use of an Exchange Server in the back-end? I already have an IMAP/POP3/SMTP hMailServer running on Windows with IIS Web Server. When I bind the domain to use the autodiscover.domain.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml, I can view the XML output in a browser.

However, when I try to setup the mail client, Outlook 2013, it does not want to take it. It asks me to allow the certificate because the domain name is different, so I allow it. Then it just tries continuesly... After a while I'm stuck with a 'Server could not establish a secure connection, would you like to try uncrypted?'

I have followed quite a number of online documentation but 99% of them reference back to Exchange - which works. My scenario is Exchange-less.

Comment: What does your XML file look like?  Is it configured properly (there's a technet article on how to write it)?  Test here: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ with the `Outlook Autodiscover` test and report back the results in your original post.

Comment: info@riaandelange.co.za.
  The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer failed to obtain an Autodiscover XML response.
  
 Additional Details
  
A Web exception occurred because an HTTP 405 - MethodNotAllowed response was received from IIS7.

HTTP Response Headers:
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Length: 1293
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 20 May 2014 18:48:53 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Elapsed Time: 823 ms.

Comment: It seems like your XML file isn't responding to the POST command from Outlook correctly.  Review here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507.aspx and let me know if you have other questions or if that gets you going.

Comment: I need help, its not working... I added a Handler Mapping, but that didn't really do anything except now I'm getting 500 error. Can I hire you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know, there haven't been posts recently, but this question is still valid.

i just stumbled over this, while fighting it myself.

if you are interested, you may check out my simplistic solution here (this is not returning errors, nor does it check for other request types): https://gist.github.com/BananaAcid/4769f09887a631f4abc9a2e42ec4526b